# Set WordPress home URL to Paid Memberships Pro Checkout Page & Rewrite/Hide URL

Tags: php, regex, wordpress, .htaccess, mod-rewrite

The Problem:

1. Set the home page of WordPress to a specific Paid Memberships Pro checkout page (I don't want this to be done via a custom page template). Example:

   User visits: http://www.example.com/

   They're redirected to: http://www.example.com/membership-account/membership-checkout/?level=1
2. HIDE the URL, so that it reads simply as:

   http://www.example.com/ (the user never knows they've been redirected to a different page template)

What I've tried:

1. Set the home page to `/membership-account/membership-checkout/` via the admin (this url is missing the query string `?level=1`). Doesn't work because I'm trying to target this specific membership level. Site redirects to `/membership-account/membership-levels/`
2. Modify .htaccess to `Redirect` the user to the desired page, and then `RewriteRule` back to the root domain...results in a redirect loop error.

Thoughts for how to approach this?

Comment: I would not get through the trouble of checking all this redirection and just have a default in a switch statement, or somesuch hack

Answer (score 2, accepted):

PMPro developer here. The checkout page requires that ?level=1 parameter or it will try to redirect to your levels page.

There are a few ways to override this behavior by basically telling PMPro which level to assume on the checkout page if none is given. Here is one option, add this to your wp-config.php, active theme's functions.php, or a custom plugin:

`define("PMPRO_DEFAULT_LEVEL", "1");`

Alternatively, you can set `$_REQUEST['level']` in some code directly.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Thanks, this is an elegant solution. I appreciate the help.

Answer (score 1):

Using this in the .htaccess file should do the trick. This will still display as www.example.com in the URL bar but display the membership page.

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index.php$ /membership-account/membership-checkout/?level=1 [L]
```

Comment: This isn't doing it...at least it's not picking up the `?level=1`.

Comment: @rnevius I just copied this code over to my site and confirmed the GET variable was being read. (Instead of the membership-checkout, I created a test page that just echo'd $_GET['level']). Does the server have mod_rewrite stuff enabled?

Comment: Indeed it does...I'm getting `The requested URL /membership-account/membership-checkout/ was not found on this server.`

Comment: @rnevius Try to use the non-pretty URL, perhaps /index.php?page=981?level=1 or what not. Let me know how you make out.

Comment: This is a good idea, but having this kind of rewrite rule on the WP homepage could cause issues.